# Use C to exit ssh session to linux

Tags: c, linux, ssh

I"m running a program that runs over ssh session. Meaning I connect to a linux using putty, the program starts, using the /etc/bash.bashrc file. At some point the program suppose to end and with it the ssh session via putty should disconnect.
What I"ve done untill now with a code below, and it doesn't work: the program  exits, and stays in linux shell, meaning the putty is connected. What I expected is the command "exit" to end the putty ssh session.

```
 char file_name[20];
 pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            printf("Starting vi\r\n");
            char external_cmd[200] = "vi ";
            strcat(external_cmd, file_name);
            system(external_cmd);
        } else 
        {
            waitpid(pid,0,0);
            printf("Exit..\r\n");
            system("exit");

        }
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is never an adequate problem description. Please describe the exact expected behaviour and actual behaviour observed.

Comment: It's still not clear. What does "stays in the Linux shell" mean? The remote shell? the local shell? Best if you can show a log. `system` starts a new process. So using that to run `exit` does not cause the current process to exit. However, the process should exit when the code finishes running. You have not provided a complete example so it is not clear what happens (if anything) after the code shown (does it end there?).

Comment: Ok, edited again, hope it more clear

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to start your C program with `exec` so that it replaces the shell. The SSH session will naturally end when the program exits.

```
$ exec your_program
```

Comment: If this worked for you please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: It works, but it is not 100% what I need. I need a way to stop ssh session via the C program. I don't want the ssh session to stop in all cases on program end. In some case I want the ssh session to continue after the C program ends. So the answer is not correct from my point of view

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't accomplish anything:

```
system("exit");
```

`system()` [runs a child process under `sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html):

> The `system()` function shall behave as if a child process were
>   created using `fork()`, and the child process invoked the `sh` utility
>   using `execl()` as follows:
>
> ```
> execl(<shell path>, "sh", "-c", command, (char *)0);
> ```

So, your call to `system()` starts a `sh` process, which then executes the `exit` command you passed to it - and the child process exits, doing nothing to the parent processes.

You can kill the parent shell, though, by obtaining the PID of the parent process with [`getppid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getppid.html) and then calling [`kill()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) to kill it:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
...
pid_t parent = getppid();
kill( parent, SIGKILL );
```

`SIGKILL` is probably a bit extreme - it kills a process immediately, with no chance for the process to clean up after itself, but it *will* work (unless you're running a non-root setuid child process in this case - if you don't know what that is, don't worry about it.).  `SIGTERM` is a less-extreme signal, but since it can be caught or blocked it isn't guaranteed to end a process.  `SIGINT` is the equivalent of `CTRL-C` and may also work, but again the process can catch or ignore the signal.  `SIGQUIT` can also be used, but it's purpose is to cause the process to quit and dump a core file, which you probably don't want.